# Why does both Picker's .onReceive fire?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the swiftUI View below, there are two boolean @State variables (`boolA` and `boolB`) connected to two different pickers. Each picker has an `.onReceive`, with the following kind of publisher

```
[self.boolA].publisher.first()
```

(To be honest, I don't understand that line of code but it appears in several answers on S.O.)

In any case, *whichever* picker I change **both .onReceive fire!**

Questions: 1) Why does both onReceive fire?  2) How to avoid this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var boolA = false
@State private var boolB = false

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        Picker(selection: $boolA, label: Text("a? ")) {
            Text("a is true").tag(true)
            Text("a is false").tag(false)
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .onReceive([self.boolA].publisher.first()) { _ in
            print("on receive on boolA")
        }
        
        Picker(selection: $boolB, label: Text("b? ")) {
            Text("b is true").tag(true)
            Text("b is false").tag(false)
        }
      .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .onReceive([self.boolB].publisher.first()) { _ in
            print("on receive on boolB")
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    
}
```

}

[image: Two pickers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a single `onRecieved` in your `View`. Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var boolA = false
    @State private var boolB = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Picker(selection: $boolA, label: Text("a? ")) {
                Text("a is true").tag(true)
                Text("a is false").tag(false)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Picker(selection: $boolB, label: Text("b? ")) {
                Text("b is true").tag(true)
                Text("b is false").tag(false)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Spacer()
            .onReceive([self.boolA, self.boolB].publisher.first()) { _ in
                print("boolA:", self.boolA, "boolB:", self.boolB)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't understand why both onReceive did fire in my code.